# ORDER BY - Identical values

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Here is a **table** structure example:

```
// tablename
+----+------+---------+
| id | numb |  color  | 
+----+------+---------+
| 1  | 4    | green   |
| 2  | 4    | yellow  |
| 3  | 3    | red     |
+----+------+---------+
```

Here is a **query** example:

```
SELECT id, numb, color FROM tablename ORDER BY numb asc
```

The **result** will be:

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | numb |  color  | 
+----+------+---------+
| 3  | 3    | red     |
| 1  | 4    | green   |
| 2  | 4    | yellow  |
+----+------+---------+
```

Now, my **focus** is on the **order** of these rows:

```
| 3  | 4    | green   |
| 2  | 4    | yellow  |
```

Because their `numb` values are equal, Now I want to know, for several executing that query, they will be constant? (*Is order guaranteed for the identical values?)* Or there isn't any guarantee and I should use another column name in the query like this `ORDER BY numb, id asc` ?

Comment: No. In simple terms, there is no guarantee. If you want items returned in a specific order, then you should always specify that order.

Comment: you should include id in the order by

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** No, there is no guarantee. (as @Strawberry wrote under the question)

**Full answer:** You can add a new column named `sort_identical`, And fill it whatever you like. And then use this:

```
... ORDER BY numb, sort_identical asc
```

*(Also you can use `id` instead of creating a new column - But if you need to sort it differently than `id`, then create a new column)*

```
+----+------+---------+----------------+
| id | numb |  color  | sort_identical |
+----+------+---------+----------------+
| 3  | 3    | red     | 1              |
| 1  | 4    | green   | 2              |
| 2  | 4    | yellow  | 3              |
+----+------+---------+----------------+
```